Extension/application to extract an project and dependencies to a new solution
I look for an application/extension that allows to, given an complex solution file (.sln),  take an application and it's dependent projects to a new solution file.
Moving/packing the projects to an zip file is desirable, but optional.
I don't care for nuget dependencies, an nugget restore is more than acceptable.
